# Combine two data-frames on conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

**Issue**:

I have two tables with sample inputs below:

*Baseline_Cars*:

| Name | Fname | FW_Base | Seq | FP_Base | FW_Prop | FP_Prop | isChanged | changeType |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Audi | A1 | 2 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | "" |
| Audi | A2 | 3 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | "" |
| Audi | A3 | 4 | 0 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 | "" |
| BMW | X1 | 5 | 0 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 0 | "" |
| BMW | X2 | 6 | 0 | 6 | 0 | 0 | 0 | "" |
| Merc | M4 | 7 | 0 | 7 | 0 | 0 | 0 | "" |
| Merc | M5 | 8 | 0 | 8 | 0 | 0 | 0 | "" |

*Proposed_Cars*:

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4(FW_Base) | 5(FW_Prop) | 6(FP_Base) | 7(FP_Prop) | 8(isChanged) | 9(changeType) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 144 | Audi | A1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | W |
| 144 | Audi | A2 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 1 | 1 | P |
| 144 | BMW | X1 | 5 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 1 | W |
| 144 | BMW | X2 | 6 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 1 | W |

**Expected** **Solution**:

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4(FW_Base) | 5(FW_Prop) | 6(FP_Base) | 7(FP_Prop) | 8(isChanged) | 9(changeType) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 144 | Audi | A1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | W |
| 144 | Audi | A2 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 1 | 1 | P |
| 144 | Audi | A3 | 4 | 0 | 4 | 0 | 0 | NULL |
| 144 | BMW | X1 | 5 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 1 | W |
| 144 | BMW | X2 | 6 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 1 | W |

*Explanation of the expected solution:*

1. Baseline cars contain names of car brands with Fnames, baseline weights(FW_Base),baseline Parameters(FP_Base).
2. Proposed cars contain names of cars with Proposed new weights(FW_PROP) and new Parameters(FP_PROP).
3. By default the FW_PROP, FP_PROP, isChanged are 0 in Baseline cars  and changeType column is empty string.
4. isChanged=1 in Proposed cars tells that new weights or parameters have been suggested(if changeType = W, new weight change or changeType=P, new Parameter change)
5. I wish to merge the tables on the condition that if the *Fname in Proposed cars exists in Baseline cars, we substitute the respective columns in Baseline_Cars, along with imputing NULL for changeType incase no change were made. (e.g Audi A3 row)*

Snippet code to generate the above sample input data:

```
baseline_cars = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Name','Fname','FW_Base','Seq','FP_Base','FW_Prop','FP_Prop','isChanged','ChangeType'])

proposed_cars = pd.DataFrame(columns=['1','2','3','4(FW_Base)','5(FW_Prop)','6(FP_Base)','7(FP_Prop)','8(isChanged)','9(ChangeType)'])

baseline_cars = baseline_cars.append({'Name':'Audi','Fname':'A1','FW_Base':2,'Seq':0,'FP_Base':2,'FW_Prop':0,'FP_Prop':0,'isChanged':0,'ChangeType':""}, ignore_index=True)
baseline_cars = baseline_cars.append({'Name':'Audi','Fname':'A2','FW_Base':3,'Seq':0,'FP_Base':3,'FW_Prop':0,'FP_Prop':0,'isChanged':0,'ChangeType':""}, ignore_index=True)
baseline_cars = baseline_cars.append({'Name':'Audi','Fname':'A3','FW_Base':4,'Seq':0,'FP_Base':4,'FW_Prop':0,'FP_Prop':0,'isChanged':0,'ChangeType':""}, ignore_index=True)
baseline_cars = baseline_cars.append({'Name':'BMW','Fname':'X1','FW_Base':5,'Seq':0,'FP_Base':5,'FW_Prop':0,'FP_Prop':0,'isChanged':0,'ChangeType':""}, ignore_index=True)
baseline_cars = baseline_cars.append({'Name':'BMW','Fname':'X2','FW_Base':6,'Seq':0,'FP_Base':6,'FW_Prop':0,'FP_Prop':0,'isChanged':0,'ChangeType':""}, ignore_index=True)
baseline_cars = baseline_cars.append({'Name':'Merc','Fname':'M4','FW_Base':7,'Seq':0,'FP_Base':7,'FW_Prop':0,'FP_Prop':0,'isChanged':0,'ChangeType':""}, ignore_index=True)
baseline_cars = baseline_cars.append({'Name':'Merc','Fname':'M5','FW_Base':8,'Seq':0,'FP_Base':8,'FW_Prop':0,'FP_Prop':0,'isChanged':0,'ChangeType':""}, ignore_index=True)

proposed_cars = proposed_cars.append({'1':144,'2':'Audi','3':'A1','4(FW_Base)':2,'5(FW_Prop)':1,'6(FP_Base)':1,'7(FP_Prop)':1,'8(isChanged)':1,'9(ChangeType)':"W"}, ignore_index=True)
proposed_cars = proposed_cars.append({'1':144,'2':'Audi','3':'A2','4(FW_Base)':3,'5(FW_Prop)':3,'6(FP_Base)':3,'7(FP_Prop)':1,'8(isChanged)':1,'9(ChangeType)':"P"}, ignore_index=True)
proposed_cars = proposed_cars.append({'1':144,'2':'BMW','3':'X1','4(FW_Base)':5,'5(FW_Prop)':3,'6(FP_Base)':3,'7(FP_Prop)':3,'8(isChanged)':1,'9(ChangeType)':"W"}, ignore_index=True)
proposed_cars = proposed_cars.append({'1':144,'2':'BMW','3':'X2','4(FW_Base)':6,'5(FW_Prop)':4,'6(FP_Base)':4,'7(FP_Prop)':4,'8(isChanged)':1,'9(ChangeType)':"W"}, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Honestly I have tried to merge using Fname as the key but haven't been able to produce the exact table as I expected and the progress I made so far was not really worth adding in my question, so pardon I had to ask without giving my inputs above.

Comment: it may need to write own function which may need for-loops. But maybe you should first merge all values into one DataFrame and later filter rows and modify columns in this single DataFrame.

Comment: There are higher chances somebody will answer this question if you provide data than can help in creating dataframe easily

Comment: Hi, I thought providing tabular structure of input tables was well enough to create dataframe, dont you think ?

Comment: I get your point but don't you think people will be more inclined to attempt the problem if dummy data is given just as pd.DataFrame rather than manually creating one

Comment: Thanks Abhishek, I have added the same. Appreciate your help if you could figure this one out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check Below code, sharing raw data also that is being used for clarity (created it before it was shared in Question)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

Baseline_Cars = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Audi','Audi','Audi','BMW','BMW','Merc','Merc',],
                              'Fname':['A1','A2','A3','X1','X2','M4','M5',],
                              'FW_Base':['2','3','4','5','6','7','8',],
                              'Seq':['0','0','0','0','0','0','0',],
                              'FP_Base':['2','3','4','5','6','7','8',],
                              'FW_Prop':['0','0','0','0','0','0','0',],
                              'FP_Prop':['0','0','0','0','0','0','0',],
                              'isChanged':['0','0','0','0','0','0','0',],
                              'changeType':["","","","","","","",]
                              })

Proposed_Cars = pd.DataFrame({'1':['144','144','144','144',],
                              '2':['Audi','Audi','BMW','BMW',],
                              '3':['A1','A2','X1','X2',],
                              '4(FW_Base)':['2','3','5','6',],
                              '5(FW_Prop)':['1','3','3','4',],'6(FP_Base)':['1','3','3','4',],
                              '7(FP_Prop)':['1','1','3','4',],'8(isChanged)':['1','1','1','1',],
                              '9(changeType)':['W','P','W','W',]})

merged_df = pd.merge(Baseline_Cars,Proposed_Cars, left_on=['Name','Fname'], right_on = ['2','3'], how='left' )

merged_df = merged_df[merged_df['Name'].isin(Proposed_Cars['2'].tolist())]

merged_df = merged_df.drop(['2','3'], axis=1).rename(columns={'Name':'2','Fname':'3'})

common_cols = [(j,i) for  j in Proposed_Cars for i in Baseline_Cars if j.find(i)> -1]

merged_df[[i[0] for i in common_cols]] = merged_df.apply(lambda x: ','.join([x[i[1]] if (str(x[i[0]]) == 'nan') else x[i[0]] for i in common_cols]), axis=1).astype('str').str.split(',', expand=True)

merged_df[['1','2','3']+[i[0] for i in common_cols]].ffill().replace('',np.NaN)
```

Output:

[image]

Update - as per OP' comments below, it works with data shared in question

```
merged_df = pd.merge(baseline_cars,proposed_cars, left_on=['Name','Fname'], right_on = ['2','3'], how='left' )

merged_df = merged_df[merged_df['Name'].isin(proposed_cars['2'].tolist())]

merged_df = merged_df.drop(['2','3'], axis=1).rename(columns={'Name':'2','Fname':'3'})

common_cols = [(j,i) for  j in proposed_cars for i in baseline_cars if j.find(i)> -1]

merged_df[[i[0] for i in common_cols]] = merged_df.apply(lambda x: ','.join([ str(x[i[1]]) if (str(x[i[0]]) == 'nan') else str(x[i[0]]) for i in common_cols]), axis=1).astype('str').str.split(',', expand=True)

merged_df[[i[0] for i in common_cols][:-1]] = merged_df[[i[0] for i in common_cols][:-1]].astype('int') 

merged_df[['1','2','3']+[i[0] for i in common_cols]].ffill().replace('',np.NaN)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer but you have passed all values as string and not as int/float which is an issue.

Comment: Please check updated code, checked with data shared in question